# Laravel VueJS Update view triggered by DB changes

Tags: laravel, database, vue.js, iot

I'm tyring to modify views on a Laravel/VueJS project when DB data changes.

The thing that modifies DB is not the backend of Laravel project, is a IoT platform connected to the DB.

Because of this, i don't think Broadcastings are an option and I don't what should I use

Comment: You can fetch up-to-date values using ajax or you need some background process that stores last value from DB in cache and compares it to new one. Don't know much about your app to know what would be the best solution

Comment: My App print a HTML div at a determined pixel, coming that position from an InfluxDB. That div is a representation of a real life device detected by an IoT device. Whenever the IoT detects changes on a device by a sensor, it will add data to the InfluxDB and that should be read in real time by the App to change HTML div style.

Comment: Another option is to listen to IoT broker from PHP is it's important to minimize delay